# Making animation clip at runtime from available sprites

Tags: unity, c#, animation

i have sprite sheets of different resolution for **targeting different mobile/tablet resolutions**. the problem is that i have to choose sprite sheets from all the available one depending upon target resolution to make the animation clip and assign them to the Animation Override Controller at run time.
i found this link to make the animation clip.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1080430/create-animation-clip-from-sprites-programmaticall.html

and the code works but only in unity editor i.e. whenever i try to build the project i get the following error:The type or namespace name `UnityEditor' could not be found.so i want to do the same thing but for different environments not only the editor.

look at this forum:https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/creating-animation-clip-at-runtime-from-sprites-2d.439792/

i wasn't able to find any solutions to this problem of making animation clips dynamically at runtime so please help me.

Comment: Do you need to generate a new clip at runtime? Two alternatives suggest themselves: **1)** use a single clip for the animation, based on a tiny control map. Then in LateUpdate, swap all the control map's sprites for their corresponding members in the spritesheet you want to use. This technique is often used to share animations between characters with different sprites. Or, **2)** Use the code you have now to generate animation clips for each resolution at edit time, save them, and pack them into your game. At runtime, select whichever pre-existing clip matches your current needs.

Comment: sorry i wasn't able to understand it earlier . i have got the idea now .